# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to By

Tags: java, selenium

Hello I am very new to java, Eclipse is giving me an error:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to By
```

Below is my code:

```
public boolean currentMonthActivity(){ 
    selectSecondMonth.click(); 
    return Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]")[1]).size () > 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `By.xpath` return? Apparently it's not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

You wrote

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]")[1]
```

in your return statement. That is, you try to access the result of `By#xpath` like an array by using `[1]`. However, the method does **not return an array**, it returns a `By`.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#xpath-java.lang.String-) of the method:

> **Returns**: A `By` which locates elements via *XPath*.

---

### Solution

You probably intended to access the result of `Driver.findElements` like an array. However, the exact return type is `List<WebElement>` (see [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)), that is not an array. You would access it like

```
return Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]")).get(1);
```

However, this access only works if there is more than one element (you are trying to access the second element). So a safe variant would be:

```
List<WebElement> elements = Driver.findElements(By.xpath(
    "//div[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]"));

if (elements.size() > 1) {
    return elements.get(1);
} else {
    // Do something different
}
```

But I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want, since you seem to return a `boolean`. Feel free to explain it in more detail and I'll update the solution.